# mySQL SELECT in between dates and with conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a melt down and my experience with SQL is somehow limited, for these kind of purposes. Say I have the two following tables:

customer_list:

```
id    |    email
-----------------------------------
1     |    mail1@mail.com
2     |    mail2@mail.com
3     |    mail3@mail.com
```

payment_log

```
customer_id    |    payment_date    |    payment_type_id
-------------------------------------------------------------
1              |    2016-01-01      |    3
1              |    2016-01-05      |    3
1              |    2016-01-02      |    2
1              |    2016-04-01      |    1
1              |    2016-04-12      |    2
2              |    2016-01-13      |    1
2              |    2016-01-19      |    1
2              |    2016-01-07      |    1
2              |    2016-01-04      |    1
3              |    2016-04-15      |    2
```

The customers I wish to select must in this example live up to the following criteria:

- Must have made a payment before 2016-03-22, with any payment type, EXCEPT payment_type_id = 3.
- Must have made at least one payment after 2016-03-22, using payment_type_id = 3.

The customer I need as a result of the query is customer_id = 1.

Comment: You need to fulfill either one condition right ?

Comment: Try this query "SELECT customer_id  FROM payment_log WHERE (payment_date < '2016-03-22' AND payment_type_id!=3) OR (payment_date>2016-03-22 AND payment_type_id=3)";

Comment: Needs both criteria :)

Comment: @EibergDK, I think you'll get what you need from my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM customer
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT L1.customer_id AS id
    FROM payment_log L1
    LEFT JOIN payment_log L2 ON L1.customer_id = L2.customer_id
    WHERE
        L1.payment_date < '2016-03-22'
    AND L2.payment_date > '2016-03-22' AND L2.payment_type_id = 3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use an inner join on the same table

```
SELECT distinct a.customer_id FROM payment_log  as a
INNER JOIN payment_log as b 
        on (a.customer_id = b.customer_id and a.payment_date = b.payment_date)
WHERE (a.payment_date < '2016-03-22' AND a.payment_type_id!=3)
AND  (b.payment_date>2016-03-22 AND b.payment_type_id=3)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
SELECT customer_id 
FROM payment_log 
WHERE payment_date =< '2016-03-22' AND payment_type_id != '3');
```

Comment: This would only satisfy one condition

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT customer_id 
FROM 
  payment_log 
WHERE 
    (payment_date < '2016-03-22' AND payment_type_id != 3) 
  AND 
    customer_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT customer_id FROM payment_log WHERE payment_date > 2016-03-22 AND payment_type_id = 3);
```

You might have to massage the sql syntax a little, but it should give you what you need.